# How to create a Thread-safe ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Android documentation says

> ContentProvider methods can be called from various ContentResolver
>   objects in different processes and threads, they must be implemented
>   in a thread-safe manner

And I found this post on Stackoverflow
[Android - sqlite content providers and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912793/android-sqlite-content-providers-and-multithreading)
which says it's thread safe already ??

So, Just wondering how to create a thread-safe `ContentProvider` ? Is it enough if I make the insert/update/delete methods `syncronized`

```
public synchronized Uri insert (Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

}
```

Comment: I have multiple threads inserting data into the same database/table

Comment: Please read through what other people wrote in: [What are the best practices for SQLite on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-are-the-best-practices-for-sqlite-on-android/3689883#3689883). It should clarify things for you.

Comment: Yeah but what if you have a multiple threads updating and deleting

Answer (score 14):

You could make every method `synchronized`, **but make sure it is absolutely necessary before you do**. In cases where the underlying data source is already thread-safe making the methods `synchronized` could be costly. See my [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/10/sqlite-contentprovider-thread-safety.html) on this topic for more information.

Comment: Even if you make each method synchronized...what would prevent a request to Update and a request to Delete coming in at the same time, thus causing thread safety.  Seems to me each of these methods needs to wait for a semaphore to clear before continuing.  Or better yet these methods all use a queue...

Comment: @JPM Yeah, you're absolutely right. In the case that you are using an `SQLiteDatabase` as the underlying source, this shouldn't matter (`SQLiteDatabase` is thread safe). Other than that, there are no guarantees... you'd have to either synchronize the data source or synchronize access to the `ContentProvider` (I would suggest the former).

Comment: How would you synchronize the Datasource/DataBaseHelper class that ContentProvider uses?  Maybe I should ask this as a question... seems something others have not answered on this site.

Comment: @JPM It depends on the data source, I guess. What is the data source you need to synchronize?

Comment: I have a SQlite datasource, my issue is multiple threads and multiple applications can access the ContentProvider at the same time.

Comment: @JPM Yeah, so that's what I'm saying... you don't need to worry about thread safety then since `SQLiteDatabase` provides it for you. See the link to my blog post on this in my answer.

Comment: SQLiteDatabase class implements thread-safety by using ReentrantLock though it can be explicitly switched off if you really need it with setLockingEnabled(). But it is enabled by default.

Comment: @JPM (very late reply to your first comment) If you simply add the `synchronized` keyword to both, the `update` and `delete` methods, both methods will try to acquire a lock for the same object (the ContentProvider) and thus they will not execute simultaneously either.