# Using the Sherlock ViewPager and FragmetPagerAdapter

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using the `FragmentPagerAdapter` in my application. In the Adapter I have the following code:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            return OffersBasicInfoFragment.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return OffersSelectedCategoriesFragment.newInstance();
        case 2:
            return OffersManageArtworkFragment.newInstance();
        case 3:
            return OffersLegalDisclaimerFragment.newInstance();
        case 4:
            return OffersSelectStoresFragment.newInstance();
        case 5:
            return OffersPreviewSaveOfferFragment.newInstance();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now in my `onViewCreated` function I have various network calls. Now all of these seven pages get called at the same time. How do I structure my code such that only when the current page is active are the calls made. Meaning when I swipe from  Tab1 to Tab2 should the calls in the Tab2 fragment be called.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Is a very good practice put break statement in each case.

Comment: @ArnaldoGaspar don't be silly, break after return is invalid syntax

Comment: Shure, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You probably suffer from poor Fragment design.

Strange is that ViewPager should pre-cache only like first 2-3 fragments (including the one currently visible)

Maybe using `setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)` could give you possibility to create only current fragment, or not more than two at the same time.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

---

Steps I'd have checked if I were you

2. Use Service and/or ContentProvider to avoid caching and concurrency problems
3. Try to use `Fragment.setUserVisibleHint` to start network call when user can really see the Fragment contents
4. If using HttpClient, try to create singleton and set `maxConnectionsPerHost` and `maxTotalConnections` to allow one request at time

Links to study on:

- http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/threading.html
- [How to determine when Fragment becomes visible in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager)
- [Is Fragment.setUserVisibleHint() called by the android System?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731589/is-fragment-setuservisiblehint-called-by-the-android-system)
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)
- [How to create a Thread-safe ContentProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481978/how-to-create-a-thread-safe-contentprovider)
- [Sync data between Android App and webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829371/sync-data-between-android-app-and-webserver)